# Firebase notification doesn't appear on device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I pause my app in `OnTokenRefresh()`, copy the token, put the app into the background and then send a message using Firebase console and it says the token is not registered.

The advice is that the device will only receive a notification if it's backgrounded, and yet the act of backgrounding the app seems to unregister the token.

Why does this happen?

Comment: lol, thanks André.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In the old Firebase Cloud Messaging It was like that but you can get data from firebase and generate the notification using the wakeful broadcast receiver

```
public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private Utils utils = new Utils();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String mediaType = intent.getExtras().getString("mediaType");
//        Log.e("BroadcastReceiver::", "BroadcastReceiver");
        if (mediaType != null) {
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
            String imageUri = intent.getExtras().getString("image");
            String newsId = intent.getExtras().getString("newsId");
            Intent floating = new Intent(context, ChatHeadService.class);
            floating.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri);
            floating.putExtra("newsId", newsId);
            floating.putExtra("message", message);
            floating.putExtra("mediaType", mediaType);
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri, context);
            sendNotification(context, message, bitmap, imageUri, newsId, mediaType, null);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) {
                    utils.cToast("Please enable Overlay permission for My News", context);
                    Intent settingIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                            Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
                    settingIntent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(settingIntent);
                } else if (utils.getPrefernces(context, "dnd") == null)
                    context.startService(floating);
                else if (utils.getPrefernces(context, "dnd").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                    context.startService(floating);
            } else if (utils.getPrefernces(context, "dnd") == null)
                context.startService(floating);
            else if (utils.getPrefernces(context, "dnd").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                context.startService(floating);
        }
    }

    public void sendNotification(Context context, String messageBody, Bitmap image, String imageUri, String newsId, String mediaType, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = null;

        switch (mediaType) {

            case "print":

                intent = new Intent(context, FullPrintMedia.class);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("nid", newsId);
                intent.putExtra("mediaType", mediaType);
                break;

            case "electronic":

                intent = new Intent(context, FullElectronicMedia.class);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("nid", newsId);
                intent.putExtra("mediaType", mediaType);
                break;

            case "live":

                intent = new Intent(context, Live.class);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;

            case "update":

                //Open the app page in Google Play store:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=live.mynews.app"));
                intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                break;

            case "add_friend":

                intent = new Intent(context, Collapsinglayout.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", newsId);
                intent.putExtra("userName", messageBody.substring(0, messageBody.indexOf(' ')));
                intent.putExtra("userImage", imageUri);
                intent.putExtra("isFriend", 3);
                break;

            case "accept_friend":

                intent = new Intent(context, Collapsinglayout.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", newsId);
                intent.putExtra("userName", messageBody.substring(0, messageBody.indexOf(' ')));
                intent.putExtra("userImage", imageUri);
                intent.putExtra("isFriend", 0);
                break;

            default:

                intent = new Intent(context, FullPrintMedia.class);
//                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("nid", newsId);
                intent.putExtra("mediaType", mediaType);
                break;
        }

//        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(new MyUtils().getNotificationIcon())
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl, Context context) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
//            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.noimageavailable);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return icon;
        }
    }
}
```

I had the same issue and wrote this logic which helped me to solve that.

But if you update the SDK it will receive the notifications in background and foreground as well